# Quiero ponerle scrollbars a mi treeview hecho con grid pero no me deja poner la horizontal

Tags: python, grid, scrollbar

No me deja poner el scrollbar horizontal y que sea funcional no se si porque tengo más de 20 columnas, pero lo he intentado de varias formas y no me deja, al momento de correrlo se ve así [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], quisiera saber que podria hacer para que se viera de manera correcta

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import END, Button, ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from Productos import*
from conexion import *

class FormularioClientes:
   global root
   root = None

   global name_entry
   name_entry = None

   global ds_entry
   ds_entry = None

   global dp_entry
   dp_entry = None

   global w_entry
   w_entry = None

   global v_entry
   v_entry = None

   global hsc_entry
   hsc_entry = None

   global SNP_PROV_entry
   SNP_PROV_entry = None

   global t_entry
   t_entry = None

   global ip_entry
   ip_entry = None

   global m_entry
   m_entry = None

   global p_entry
   p_entry = None

   global lp_entry
   lp_entry = None

   global ti_entry
   ti_entry = None

   global sp_entry
   sp_entry = None

   global cid_entry
   cid_entry = None

   global df_entry
   df_entry = None

   global UCI_entry
   UCI_entry = None

   global b_entry
   b_entry = None

   global po_entry
   po_entry = None

   global so_entry
   so_entry = None

   global D_entry
   D_entry = None

   global treeFrame
   treeFrame = None

   
   
def Formulario():
     global name_entry
     global ds_entry
     global dp_entry
     global w_entry
     global v_entry
     global hsc_entry
     global SNP_PROV_entry
     global t_entry
     global ip_entry
     global m_entry
     global p_entry
     global lp_entry
     global ti_entry
     global sp_entry
     global cid_entry
     global df_entry
     global UCI_entry
     global b_entry
     global po_entry
     global so_entry
     global D_entry
     global treeFrame



     root = tk.Tk()


     style = ttk.Style(root)
     root.tk.call("source", "forest-light.tcl")
     root.tk.call("source", "forest-dark.tcl")
     root.geometry("1200x540")
     style.theme_use("forest-dark")

     frame = ttk.Frame(root)

     frame.pack()

     widgets_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Insert Row")
     widgets_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

     name_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     name_entry.insert(0, "Name")
     name_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: name_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     name_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     ds_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     ds_entry.insert(0, "Description Sale")
     ds_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: ds_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     ds_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     dp_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     dp_entry.insert(0, "Description Purchase")
     dp_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: dp_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     dp_entry.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     w_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     w_entry.insert(0, "Weight")
     w_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: w_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     w_entry.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     v_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     v_entry.insert(0, "Volume")
     v_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: v_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     v_entry.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     hsc_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     hsc_entry.insert(0, "HS Code")
     hsc_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: hsc_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     hsc_entry.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     SNP_PROV_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     SNP_PROV_entry.insert(0, "Studio No° de parte Proovedor")
     SNP_PROV_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: SNP_PROV_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     SNP_PROV_entry.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     t_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     t_entry.insert(0, "Type")
     t_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: t_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     t_entry.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     ip_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     ip_entry.insert(0, "Invoice Policy")
     ip_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: v_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     ip_entry.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     m_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     m_entry.insert(0, "UOM ID")
     m_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: m_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     m_entry.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     p_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     p_entry.insert(0, "UOMP ID")
     p_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: p_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     p_entry.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     lp_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     lp_entry.insert(0, "List Price")
     lp_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: lp_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     lp_entry.grid(row=11, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     ti_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     ti_entry.insert(0, "IVA")
     ti_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: ti_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     ti_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     sp_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     sp_entry.insert(0, "Standar Price")
     sp_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: sp_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     sp_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     cid_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     cid_entry.insert(0, "Category ID")
     cid_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: cid_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     cid_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     df_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     df_entry.insert(0, "Default Code")
     df_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: df_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     df_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     UCI_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     UCI_entry.insert(0, "UNSPSC Code ID")
     UCI_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: UCI_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     UCI_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     b_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     b_entry.insert(0, "Barcode")
     b_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: b_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     b_entry.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     po_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     po_entry.insert(0, "Purchase Ok")
     po_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: po_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     po_entry.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     so_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     so_entry.insert(0, "Sales Ok" )
     so_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: so_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     so_entry.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     D_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
     D_entry.insert(0, "Division" )
     D_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: D_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
     D_entry.grid(row=8, column=1, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

     Button(widgets_frame,text ="Guardar", width=10, command= GuardarRegistros).grid(row=12, column=0)
     Button(widgets_frame,text ="Eliminar", width=10).grid(row=12, column=1)
     Button(widgets_frame,text ="Modificar", width=10).grid(row=13, column=0)
     Button(widgets_frame,text ="Buscar", width=10).grid(row=13, column=1)
     separator = ttk.Separator(widgets_frame)
     separator.grid(row=9, column=1, padx=(20, 10), pady=10, sticky="ew")
     treeFrame = ttk.Frame(frame)
     treeFrame.grid(row=0, column=3, pady=10,)
```

> Aqui intente poner los scrollbar pero como se que python funciona con espaciados no se si es ese mi problema

```
     hscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
     hscrollbar.place(x=530, y=1200, width=200)
     hscrollbar.set("0.5", "0.6")
     
     vscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=tk.VERTICAL)
     vscrollbar.place(x=50, y=50, height=200)
     vscrollbar.set("0.0", "0.1")
     cols = ("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23")
     treeview = ttk.Treeview(treeFrame, show="headings",
                        columns=cols, height=20)
    

     treeview.column("01", width=20)
     treeview.heading("01",text="ID",)
     treeview.column("02", width=90)
     treeview.heading("02", text="Name")
     treeview.column("03", width=190)
     treeview.heading("03", text="Description Purchase")
     treeview.column("04", width=10)
     treeview.heading("04", text="Description Sale")
     treeview.column("05", width=100)
     treeview.heading("05", text="Weight")
     treeview.column("06", width=100)
     treeview.heading("06", text="Volume")
     treeview.column("07", width=100)
     treeview.heading("07", text="HS Code")
     treeview.column("08", width=100)
     treeview.heading("08", text="Studio No° de parte Proovedor")
     treeview.column("09", width=100)
     treeview.heading("09", text="Type")
     treeview.column("10", width=100)
     treeview.heading("10", text="Invoice Policy")
     treeview.column("11", width=100)
     treeview.heading("11", text="UOM ID")
     treeview.column("12", width=100)
     treeview.heading("12", text="UOMP ID")
     treeview.column("13", width=100)
     treeview.heading("13", text="List Price")
     treeview.column("14", width=100)
     treeview.heading("14", text="IVA")
     treeview.column("15", width=100)
     treeview.heading("15", text="Standar Price")
     treeview.column("16", width=100)
     treeview.heading("16", text="Category ID")
     treeview.column("17", width=100)
     treeview.heading("17", text="Default Code")
     treeview.column("18", width=100)
     treeview.heading("18", text="UNSPSC Code ID")
     treeview.column("19", width=100)
     treeview.heading("19", text="Barcode")
     treeview.column("20", width=100)
     treeview.heading("20", text="Purchase Ok")
     treeview.column("21", width=100)
     treeview.heading("21", text="Purchase Ok")
     treeview.column("22", width=100)
     treeview.heading("22", text="Sales Ok")
     treeview.column("23", width=100)
     treeview.heading("23", text="Division")

     treeview.pack()
     
    
     #Agregar datos a la Tabla
     #Mostrar la tabla 
     for row in PProductos.MostrarProductos():
        treeview.insert("","end",values=row)

     root.mainloop()

def GuardarRegistros():
 
 global name_entry,ds_entry,dp_entry,w_entry,v_entry,hsc_entry,SNP_PROV_entry,t_entry,ip_entry,m_entry,p_entry,lp_entry,ti_entry,sp_entry,cid_entry,df_entry,UCI_entry,b_entry,po_entry,so_entry,D_entry,treeFrame
 entry = ("name_entry,ds_entry,dp_entry,w_entry,v_entry,hsc_entry,SNP_PROV_entry,t_entry,ip_entry,m_entry,p_entry,lp_entry,ti_entry,sp_entry,cid_entry,df_entry,UCI_entry,b_entry,po_entry,so_entry,D_entry,treeFrame")

 try:
  #Verificar si los widgets esten inicialisados 
     if entry is None:
         print("Los widgets no estan inicializados")
         return
     Nombres = name_entry.get()
     Description_Purchase = dp_entry.get()
     description_Sale = ds_entry.get()
     Peso= w_entry.get()
     Volumen =v_entry.get()
     Codigo_HSC = hsc_entry.get()
     No_Parte_Proov=SNP_PROV_entry.get()
     tipo= t_entry.get()
     InvoiceP = ip_entry.get()
     Medidas=m_entry.get()
     Medidas_USA=p_entry.get()
     lisp_Price=lp_entry.get()
     IVA=ti_entry.get()
     Standar_Price=sp_entry.get()
     Category=cid_entry.get()
     DefaultCode=df_entry.get()
     UnsCodeID=UCI_entry.get()
     barcode=b_entry.get()
     purchaseok=po_entry.get()
     salesok=so_entry.get()
     Division=D_entry.get()
     PProductos.ingresarProductos(Nombres,Description_Purchase,description_Sale, 
                                Peso,Volumen,Codigo_HSC,No_Parte_Proov,tipo,
                                InvoiceP,Medidas,Medidas_USA,lisp_Price,IVA,
                                Standar_Price,Category,DefaultCode,UnsCodeID,
                                barcode,purchaseok,salesok,Division)
     messagebox.showinfo("Informacion","Los datos fueron Guardados")
     #Limpiar los campos
     name_entry.delete(0,END)
     dp_entry.delete(0,END)
     ds_entry.delete(0,END)
     w_entry.delete(0,END)
     v_entry.delete(0,END)
     hsc_entry.delete(0,END)
     SNP_PROV_entry.delete(0,END)
     t_entry.delete(0,END)
     ip_entry.delete(0,END)
     m_entry.delete(0,END)
     p_entry.delete(0,END)
     lp_entry.delete(0,END)
     ti_entry.delete(0,END)
     sp_entry.delete(0,END)
     cid_entry.delete(0,END)
     df_entry.delete(0,END)
     UCI_entry.delete(0,END)
     b_entry.delete(0,END)
     po_entry.delete(0,END)
     so_entry.delete(0,END)
     D_entry.delete(0,END)
 except ValueError as error:
    print("Error al ingresar los datos{}".format(error))

Formulario()
```

> Ya he intentado de todo tipo de cosas pero simplemente no puedo hacer que funcione ya sea horizontal o vertical no se si se me esta olvidando algo ocomo habia dicho el tamaño de las columnas

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas a tener en cuenta:

- Si tus *scrollbars* son solo para el *treeview*, lo más lógico es posicionarlas dentro del mismo *frame* que éste. Ahora mismo estas usando `place` para posicionarlas en la ventana principal.
- Debes forzar al *treeview* a restringir su anchura (y eventualmente su altura), en caso contrario se expandirá fuera de los limites de la pantalla y la *scroollbar* será inútil. Esto se puede conseguir asignando un peso a la columna del frame que ocupa el *treeview* y a su *frame* contenedor.
- Tienes que asociar la *scrollbar* al *treeview* y viceversa para que al desplazar uno el otro responda de forma acorde.

El código relevante a modificar es el siguiente:

```
# ...
# separator.grid(row=9, column=1, padx=(20, 10), pady=10, sticky="ew")

tree_frame = ttk.Frame(frame)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
tree_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
tree_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
tree_frame.grid(row=0, column=3, pady=22, sticky="ns")
 
cols = tuple(f"{n:0>2}" for n in range(1, 24))
treeview = ttk.Treeview(
    tree_frame, show="headings", columns=cols, height=20
)
treeview.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ns')
 
vscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(
    tree_frame, orient="vertical", command=treeview.yview
)
treeview.configure(yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
vscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

hscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(
    tree_frame, orient="horizontal", command=treeview.xview
)
treeview.configure(xscrollcommand=hscrollbar.set)
hscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

# treeview.column("01", width=20)
# ...
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]